# the right grain of a fact table in data warehouse

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, fact-table

we are creating star schema in our new data warehouse which will be use in Tableau as our main BI tool.

we have order,product,supplier,plant,price.demands per yearand year of demands.

So if we create a fact table of the grain of year of demands then you have for example you will have maybe just one row for one order with one product , one supplier , one plant with one year of demands and a price for that product. If you have more than 1 year of demands like  year 2023 has demands of 10 pieces and year 2024 of 20 pieces. Then you have 2 rows in the fact table.
Imagine you want to visualize it in Tableau. With all that fields it will be fine but because there are 2 rows of data then if using just order,product,supplier and price then the price will be summed up which be incorrect. If there are many years of demands then it will be worse.

How to design the fact table?

Comment: If price is not a measure then why is it in your fact table and not, for example, as an attribute of Product? If it is a measure then just because it’s in your fact table doesn’t mean you have to sum it; measures can be semi-additive and therefore only logically aggregateable by certain dimensions

Comment: @NivkW. this was my consideration as well to use it is a product dimension as a column. Yes it could be semi-additive. But It is hard to achive in a BI yool like Tableau cause the meassure will be aggregated if it is a meqssure and not a dimension.You can use AVG instead of SUM but could be confusing in that way